# Is it possible to animate view properties during UIStoryBoardSegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I want to create a google material design-like animation that scales a round button until it fills the entire screen. while animating the scaling, the `destinationViewController` is already visible where the button has 'scaled'.

I feel like I have to access the view's property to do this, and I guess that won't work with a custom `UIStoryBoardSegue`, but I can't believe it's not possible either.

Bas

Comment: You will need to create a custom UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and do it inside this delegate I think... Hope I understood you right?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Your segue subclass has access to the source and destination view controllers, and therefore their views. You can perform whatever animations you like with these views during the `perform` method.

You can make the view controllers conform to a protocol (where the protocol defines specific subviews required for the animation), and assert if this is not the case as a safety check.